# SELinux AVC Denying "{ dyntransition }" for sshd

Tags: linux, ssh, selinux, centos8, sshd

I've tried looking around for the solution with no luck.

I have SELinux set to permissive right now on Centos 8, but if I set it to enforcing it completely disables my ability to ssh into the server. This is the journal entry:

```
setroubleshoot[2015]: setroubleshoot generated AVC, exiting to avoid recursion, context=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0, AVC scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0
setroubleshoot[2015]: audit event 
                      node=<REMOVED> type=AVC msg=audit(1633374382.599:119): avc:  denied  { dyntransition } for  pid=2003 comm="sshd" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0 tclass=process permissive=1
                      node=<REMOVED> type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1633374382.599:119): arch=c000003e syscall=1 success=yes exit=42 a0=c a1=5655238d6540 a2=2a a3=0 items=0 ppid=1985 pid=2003 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=(none) ses=3 comm="sshd" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0 key=(null)
```

/etc/sbin/sshd has the following permissions

> -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root system_u:object_r:sshd_exec_t:s0 877760 May 27 10:54 sshd

This is my sshd config

```
Port <REMOVED FOR PRIVACY>
AddressFamily inet

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV

PermitRootLogin yes

PubkeyAuthentication yes

AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no

UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding yes

PrintMotd no

AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Answer (score 1):

`Answering because I lack the rep to comment, le sigh.`

The log messages you quote suggest that there is at least one missing SELinux rule on your system: When you try to login via ssh, a transition (`dyntransition`) from one SELinux type (`kernel_t`) to another (`unconfined_t`) is being denied.

There are a couple of commands you can run to investigate:

```
ausearch -m AVC -m USER_AVC | audit2allow
```

will look for denial messages and pipe them through a command that will suggest what rules are missing on your system.

```
sesearch -c process -p dyntransition -A
```

will tell you what dyntransition rules are already present on your system. You will need to run both of those as `root` and may need to disable SELinux first (`setenforce 0`).

What puzzles me is that I find it odd that these permissions would be missing on a stock CentOS box - that suggests either an upstream regression or SELinux policy changes made post-install. Have you or anyone else changed SELinux policy on that box?